# Zend framework order before group

Tags: mysql, sorting, zend-framework, group-by

Any one have a example how to order before group with leftjoin in zend paginator adapter ?

```
new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($this->db->select()
->from(array( 'a' => $this->prefix.'contest' ), array('id'))
->joinLeft(array( 'b' => $this->prefix.'logo_to_contest'),'a.id=b.contest_id', array('img'))
->group('a.id')
->order('a.end','a.date_start DESC','b.id RAND()')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From mysql manuel

> In general, clauses used must be given in exactly the order shown in
>   the syntax description. For example, a HAVING clause must come after
>   any GROUP BY clause and before any ORDER BY clause. The exception is
>   that the INTO clause can appear either as shown in the syntax
>   description or immediately following the select_expr list.

and in the [syntax description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/select.html) group comes before order so it has nothing to do with zend 
it's mysql that requires that you put group before order.

However to get around this issue and group after ordering you can select with a subquery with order then group on a new select like :

```
$subselect = $db->select()
->from(array( 'a' => $this->prefix.'contest' ), array('id'))
->joinLeft(array( 'b' => $this->prefix.'logo_to_contest'),'a.id=b.contest_id', array())
->order('a.end','a.date_start DESC','b.id RAND()');

$select = $db->select()->from(a(array( 'a' => $this->prefix.'contest' ), array('id'))
->joinLeft(array( 'b' => $this->prefix.'logo_to_contest'),'a.id=b.contest_id', array('img'))
->where("a.id in ($subselect)")
->group('a.id');
```